# why mysql update only 1st id and fail to update the rest of id?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php
$many_bonus_id = "5#12#32"
$multi_bonus_id = str_replace("#",",",$many_bonus_id );

$up_data1['breakaway_bonus_paid'] = 1;
$this->common->updateRecord("tbl_ewallet",$up_data1, "id IN('" . $multi_bonus_id . "')");
?>
```

why mysql update only 1 record WHERE id=5, and fail to update records WHERE id=12 && id=32? How to fix it?

Comment: Because you have quotes?

Comment: With your current code, just remove the single quotes `IN(" . $multi_bonus_id . ")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing `#` with `,` will end up with a query condition of `id IN ('5,12,32')` -- essentially one item, the string "5,12,32". You need to include the quotation marks when you replace the `#`:

```
$multi_bonus_id = str_replace("#","','",$many_bonus_id );
```

Now, your query condition will be `id IN ('5','12','32')` which will check that the `id` value is one of those three options.

**Edit** (thanks @NigelRen):

Since the id values are numbers, you don't actually need the quotation marks:

```
$this->common->updateRecord("tbl_ewallet",$up_data1, "id IN(" . $multi_bonus_id . ")");
```

Now you can still replace the `#` with only a `,` and you will end up with a condition of `id IN (5,12,32)`, which will also check against those three values.

This option might be slightly more efficient if the table contains a lot of data, since the database won't need to convert strings to integers to compare them. On any modern system, you shouldn't notice a difference in speed until you get to tens or maybe hundreds of thousands of records though, so if you're not at that scale: use what makes most sense to you.

Comment: If they are numbers, then the quotes aren't needed at all.

Comment: rickdenhaan's solution is works.

Comment: @NigelRen I don't know how to remove the quote during Replacing # to ,

Comment: @NigelRen you're right, I've added that option to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Its better if we can see whats inside of "updateRecord" function.

But in this case you need to loop your update process to the number of data you wanted to update.